# Enabling AWE Memory for SQL Server 2008 on Windows 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Would you suggest using AWE Memory on Windows 2008 R2 for MS SQL 2008?

What are the benefits of using it or not using it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AWE will allow a 32-bit SQL Server to use more than 2-3 GB of RAM. If it's not a 32-bit installation of SQL Server, or the system doesn't have more RAM than that, then you don't need to enable it.

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested in this [blog](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/jonathan_kehayias/archive/2010/10/12/tsql-tuesday-11-misconceptions-enable-awe-on-64bit-sql-servers.aspx) which has detailed info regarding the issue.